# is it possible to trigger an email using microsoft flow when a date in a field of a sharepoint list item is nearby,

Tags: sharepoint-list, power-automate

I want to build a flow to trigger an email when a date in one of the fields is nearing. I have a field named Payment due date. is it possible to trigger an email 2 days prior to the Payment due date. So that I don't miss the payment due date and payment is not delayed. Any kind of assistance is appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a schedule workflow. Which will run,

- every hour
- every day
- every month

[image]

Then apply a condition where you can mention if payment due date is today, tomorrow or day after tomorrow.

When condition match you can send a notification or an email to your self.

***Brief Description***

Let's assume you have a requirement where you need a notification for payment dues before 2 days.

1. Create a schedule workflow(Scheduled—from blank)
2. Get SharePoint items
3. For each loop(Apply to each)
4. apply condition(if else),

> ```
>  formatDateTime(item()['PaymentDueDate'],'yyyy-MM-dd')
>
>  is equal to
>
>  addDays(utcNow(),2,'yyyy-MM-dd')
> ```

For more information, [reminder before the due date](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/reminder-before-the-due-date/td-p/333690)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Utkarsh. :) I have a query what should I use first while giving path to the sharepoint list and selecting the list. I am confused because if I use when an item is created or modified. it will trigger only when an item is modified .

Comment: In *Power Automate(Microsoft Flow)* you have an option to *schedule workflow*. No need of trigger like *item is created* or *item is modified*. Please check updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, Utkarsh. It worked! :)